# kiwi tcms - Gitlab bug tracker Integration

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking, kiwi-tcms

I have installed kiwi tcms on my machine with docker installation (https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html)

I have successfully created `User/TestCases/TestPlan/TestRuns` ...
But I would like to **use GitLab as my issue tracker.**

I found this documentation https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html but since I´m new as kiwi tcms user, I don´t figure out how to be able to use this.

I have my GitLab repo ready to test.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-bug-trackers

this should help clear some of the missing pieces.

You have to create a new record in the database which represents your GitLab repository. For that you need the base_url and api_password fields. They are the ones used by the integration code.

Notice that there can be several different products (repositories) on GitLab and for each one you need to create records in the Kiwi database. Otherwise Kiwi TCMS will not know how to link TestCases to issues on GitLab.

Note: GitLab integration was brough to Kiwi TCMS over the weekend by an external contributor and the new version that supports it has been literally released minutes ago. You may have to update your docker image to make use of that.