# Can't configure Gitlab as Bug tracker in Kiwi TCMS

Tags: automated-tests, gitlab, kiwi-tcms

I'm integrating gitlab as bug tracker to kiwi tcms, the problem is that I son't have the logs of the problems, ot know what is the problem, by the way I search in those links

1. [kiwi tcms - Gitlab bug tracker Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595966/kiwi-tcms-gitlab-bug-tracker-integration)
2. https://kiwitcms.org/blog/tags/customization/
3. https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration

I don't have so much information of how to do it, I don't know if I need an example, the server is running okay, and i create the test planning and runs ok, but when i want to create a bug, I can't link it to gitlab, thank u so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woa, hold your horses. "doesn't work" is a very bold statement without any context here.

For the logging part see:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#troubleshooting

Alternatively add DEBUG=True in your local_settings.py, see:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#customization

Most likely you haven't configured your integration with GitLab properly, refer to:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.Gitlab